# Strings Overflow Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to split two strings in shell script:

Something like this (For example)

```
first="Hello"
second="World"
```

So I try

```
result="$first $second"
```

And the result is:

```
"HelWord"
```

In the script I'm reading line by line a file:

```
while IFS= read line
    echo $line  
done <"exit"
```

Comment: Since you are reading from a file, most likely it is a formatting issue in the file itself.  The most common issue is when it is in Microsoft Windows format, with a line ending of `\r\n`, however it could just be that the file was created using some alien tool and contains non ASCII characters.  I suggest you do a `od -xc filename` on it and see what it contains.

Comment: Of course, DOS line endings usually manifest as the *start* of the line being overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot fit this in a comment, I'll abuse an answer.

You say the result is "HelWorld". The answer is: no it isn't.

```
ljm@verlaine[src]$ first="Hello"
ljm@verlaine[src]$ second="World"
ljm@verlaine[src]$ result="$first $second"
ljm@verlaine[src]$ echo "$result"
Hello World
```

Your loop is missing a `do` and it does nothing to concatenate strings. Further more, what you do here is read lines from a file called `exit`.  Are you sure that is what you want to do?